# Check path case sensitivity

Tags: c#, path, case-sensitive

I am trying to convert paths to a canonical form in order to compare them. I'm almost there but I'm stuck with the casing :

If the paths are not case sensitive (i.e. on Windows), my final step should be something like path = path.ToUpper() or ToLower(). On other systems (i.e. Linux, OSX), this final step should be skipped.

Is there a proper way to detect this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for [System.Environment.OSVersion](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/304283). This will detect the version of windows as well. So if you want then you can simply check if the version is Windows then do the casing else skip it.

Something like

```
System.OperatingSystem osInfo = System.Environment.OSVersion;
if(osInfo .Contains("Windows"))
{
  //Do casing
}
else
{
  //skip
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for something more "forward compatible" that could even work with new systems. Not really needed of course, it's just a matter of elegance...
I will suggest a "Path.IsCaseSensitive" to Microsoft.

Comment: That would be something you should suggest to Mono, but I doubt it would get accepted since this is a relatively simple way. Microsoft only really develops for the Windows platform, Mono handles everything else.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what OS's are case sensitive you can use the following to check

```
Environment.OSVersion.Platform
```

This is an enum with various operation systems on. You can then use this to check if you need to normalise the string or not

Answer (score 0):

You have to detect properly the OS where your code is running. After you can decide the correct strategy according the OS rules. At first look your approach is correct.
To determine the os that you are running on, try this snippet

```
var OS = System.Environment.OSVersion;
var platform = OS.Platform;
var version = OS.Version; // or OS.VersionString
var servicePack = OS.ServicePack;
if(platform=="Unix")
{
...
}
```

this can allow you to determine the compatibility. The result of "Platform" is made according the follow PlatformID enum in System.Runtime.InteropServices library.

```
// Summary:
//     Identifies the operating system, or platform, supported by an assembly.
[Serializable]
[ComVisible(true)]
public enum PlatformID
{
    // Summary:
    //     The operating system is Win32s. Win32s is a layer that runs on 16-bit versions
    //     of Windows to provide access to 32-bit applications.
    Win32S = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The operating system is Windows 95 or Windows 98.
    Win32Windows = 1,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The operating system is Windows NT or later.
    Win32NT = 2,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The operating system is Windows CE.
    WinCE = 3,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The operating system is Unix.
    Unix = 4,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The development platform is Xbox 360.
    Xbox = 5,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The operating system is Macintosh.
    MacOSX = 6,
}
```

Comment: He wasn't asking if the approach is correct, he was asking *how* to accomplish it. This should be a comment, not an answer (I know you don't have the rep, but posting comments as answers won't help get you there).